# Narrowing down a FileLoadException error on Azure

Tags: azure, f#, suave

I'm deploying a `Suave` application to `Azure web app`. The application failed with the error below (found in `eventlog.xml`).

```
<Event>
    <System>
        <Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/>
        <EventID>1026</EventID>
        <Level>0</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-12-13T22:59:39Z"/>
        <EventRecordID>-2049111390</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer></Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>
            Application: App.exe
            Framework Version: v4.0.30319
            Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
            Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException

            Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
               at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
               at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
               at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
               at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord, System.Reflection.MetadataImport, System.Reflection.Assembly ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Object[], System.Collections.IList, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
               at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Collections.IList, Boolean)
               at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.RuntimeType)
               at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(System.Type, Boolean)
               at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type, Boolean)
               at System.AppDomain.GetTargetFrameworkName()
        </Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

How do I determine the exact file which is missing or the cause of this problem so it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that you are missing some referenced `dll`, perhaps because it is not copied to the same output folder as your `App.exe`. I don't have a good suggestion on how to better debug this, sadly!

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was the `FSharp.Core.dll`. I've provided the answer below in case someone else had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was the `FSharp.Core` nuget package. Upgrading from `FSharp.Core.3.1.2.5` to  `FSharp.Core.4.0.0.1` solved it. I think the application was searching for FSharp `4.4.0.0` and this error was because it found an older version.